# Combobox: After clearing all items, adding some new, setting selected item does not work

Tags: wpf, powershell, combobox

My goal is to localise the combobox items based on the selected language. It works as expected, expect for the selected item in the combobox does not appear.

I presume clearing the previous items in the `localise_strings()` function is the reason, why this happens, however, I have no idea what condition I should add there.

I run this `localise_strings()` function in the form load and when the selected value is changed.

Below is shown the code snippet that IMO is necessary in order to help me out.

BTW, I know that the code (its algorithm) could be improved, however, for now I need to make it working.

```bsh
$l10n = [PSCustomObject]@{
    en = [PSCustomObject]@{
        selLang = 'Language'
        english = 'English'
        slovak  = 'Slovak'
    }
    sk = [PSCustomObject]@{
        selLang = 'Jazyk'
        english = 'angličtina'
        slovak  = 'slovenčina'
    }
}

function get_lang_code($lang) {
    [hashtable]$lang_meta = @{ }
    
    switch ($lang) {
        { ($_ -eq 'Slovak') -or ($_ -eq 'slovenčina') } {
            $lang_meta.lang_code = 'sk'
            $lang_meta.lang_obj_name = 'slovak'
        }
        default {
            $lang_meta.lang_code = 'en'
            $lang_meta.lang_obj_name = 'english'
        }
    }
    
    return $lang_meta
}

function localise_strings($lang) {
    # Get language code
    $lang_meta = get_lang_code($lang)
    
    # Add UI languages into combobox
    $lang_selector.Items.Clear()  # Here I think is the glitch
    $lang_selector.Items.Add($l10n.$($lang_meta.lang_code).english)
    $lang_selector.Items.Add($l10n.$($lang_meta.lang_code).slovak)
    
    # Set the localised selected value
    $lang_localised = "$($l10n.$($lang_meta.lang_code).$($lang_meta.lang_obj_name))"
    $lang_selector.SelectedValue = "$lang_localised"
    
    # Localise labels based on selected language
    $labelSelLang.Text = "$($l10n.$($lang_meta.lang_code).selLang)"
    $labelQuestion.Text = "$($lang_meta.lang_code)"
}
```

---

Note that I am absolutely new to Powershell. Also note that I use Powershell Studio.

As requested, the stripped down code is available at [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1obq3-ePgn9rQh7kNECTeQXSAca47cFIu?usp=sharing). There are two files: `stripped.psf` (Powershell Studio file) and `stripped.Run.ps1` (it was generated by Powershell Studio).

Bellow is the content of `stripped.psf` copied from Powershell Studio:

```bsh
$l10n = [PSCustomObject]@{
    en = [PSCustomObject]@{
        selLang = '&Language'
        english = 'English'
        slovak  = 'Slovak'
    }
    sk = [PSCustomObject]@{
        selLang = '&Jazyk'
        english = 'angličtina'
        slovak  = 'slovenčina'
    }
}

function get_lang_code($lang) {
    [hashtable]$lang_meta = @{ }
    
    switch ($lang) {
        { ($_ -eq 'Slovak') -or ($_ -eq 'slovenčina') } {
            $lang_meta.lang_code = 'sk'
            $lang_meta.lang_obj_name = 'slovak'
        }
        default {
            $lang_meta.lang_code = 'en'
            $lang_meta.lang_obj_name = 'english'
        }
    }
    
    return $lang_meta
}

function localise_strings($lang) {
    # Get language code
    $lang_meta = get_lang_code($lang)
    
    # Add list of localised language names into combobox
    $lang_selector.Items.Clear()
    $lang_selector.Items.Add($l10n.$($lang_meta.lang_code).english)
    $lang_selector.Items.Add($l10n.$($lang_meta.lang_code).slovak)
    
    # Set the localised selected value
    $lang_localised = "$($l10n.$($lang_meta.lang_code).$($lang_meta.lang_obj_name))"
    $lang_selector.SelectedValue = "$lang_localised"
    
    # Localise all items based on selected language
    $labelSelLang.Text = "$($l10n.$($lang_meta.lang_code).selLang)"
}

$formMachineComputerConfi_Load = {
    # Localise strings
    localise_strings('English')
}

$lang_selector_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    # Get selected language as string
    $lang = $lang_selector.SelectedItem.ToString()
    
    # Localise strings
    localise_strings($lang)
} #end lang_selector_SelectedIndexChanged

$labelSelLang_Click={
    #TODO: Place custom script here
    
}#end labelSelLang_Click
```

**Update:** When I change `$lang_selector.SelectedValue` to `$lang_selector.SelectedItem` (as @mm8 suggested in a comment below), I get the following error message. Note that I tested this with the MWE above with this change only.

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gNyY.png)

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException: The pipeline has been stopped.
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at <ScriptBlock>(Closure , FunctionContext )
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<InvokeWithPipe>b__0()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Boolean propagateAllExceptionsToTop, List`1 variablesToDefine, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, Object[] args)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeAsDelegateHelper(Object dollarUnder, Object dollarThis, Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4220.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
DebuggerProxyV5
    Assembly Version: 1.0.7233.33553
    Win32 Version: 1.1.4.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/SAPIEN%20Technologies,%20Inc/PowerShell%20Studio%202020/Debugger64/DebuggerProxyV5.DLL
----------------------------------------
PowerShellDebuggerV5
    Assembly Version: 1.1.6.0
    Win32 Version: 1.1.6.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/SAPIEN%20Technologies,%20Inc/PowerShell%20Studio%202020/Debugger64/PowerShellDebuggerV5.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Management.Automation
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management.Automation/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Management.Automation.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4200.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4220.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4200.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration.Install
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration.Install/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.Install.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.508
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.PowerShell.Security
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.WSMan.Management
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.WSMan.Management/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.WSMan.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4200.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
System.DirectoryServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.DirectoryServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.DirectoryServices.dll
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4220.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: When is `localise_strings` called? Please consider posting a complete reproducible example

Comment: When is it called? It is already in the question: I run this `localise_strings()` function **_in the form load and when the selected value is changed_**.

Comment: `ComboBox` control in Windows Forms doesn't have an event for when the selected _value_ is changed, so I was a bit perplexed by that, but I just realized you're probably using WPF then. Again, a complete example would help :)

Comment: I think I should have noted that I use Powershell Studio. :) Frankly, I have no idea how Powershell works (I prefer Bash and JavaScript), but I need to do this in Powershell.

Comment: @tukusejssirs: What value are you setting the `SelectedValue` property to? Try to set the `SelectedItem` property to a string that is actually added to `Items`. You cannot select a value that is not in the `Items` collection.

Comment: @mm8, it is as you say already; search for `$lang_selector.Items.Add` and `$labelSelLang.Text` in the question. I use the values in `$l10n.{lang_code}.{lang_name}` values, where `{lang_code}` is either `en` or `sk` and `{lang_name}` is either `english` or `slovak`. Actually, the _setting_ itself works, but it is clear immediatelly (i.e. the selected value blinks for a fraction of second and immediatelly disappears).

Comment: @tukusejssirs: Did you try to set `$lang_selector.SelectedItem` instead of `$lang_selector.SelectedValue`?

Comment: @mm8, well, it _somehow_ works (i.e. the selected value is output in the combobox), however, it freezes (a lot, esp after each language change) and in the console output, there are multiple (e.g. 6) `ERROR:` lines output (no error messsage, just `ERROR:`. I have tried to debug it using the in-built function of Powershell Studio, but no other (error) message is output.

Comment: @mm8, I have updated my question.